# I can not filter integers with CriteriaAPI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a filter functionality in a Spring Boot App, but it fails when I try to filter based on an integer.

[image: error received]

`public class StudentSearchCriteria {`
`private String firstName;`
`private String lastName;`
`private Integer yearOfStudy;`
`}`

`public class StudentPage {`
`private int pageNumber = 0;`
`private int pageSize = 1;`
`private Sort.Direction sortDirection = Sort.Direction.ASC;`
`private String sortBy = "lastName";`
`}`

`public class StudentCriteriaRepository {`

```
private final EntityManager entityManager;
private final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

public StudentCriteriaRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
}

public Page<Student> findAllWithFilters(StudentPage studentPage,
                                        StudentSearchCriteria studentSearchCriteria) {
    CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> studentRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);
    Predicate predicate = getPredicate(studentSearchCriteria, studentRoot);
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

    setOrder(studentPage, criteriaQuery, studentRoot);

    TypedQuery<Student> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    typedQuery.setFirstResult(studentPage.getPageNumber() * studentPage.getPageSize());
    typedQuery.setMaxResults(studentPage.getPageSize());

    Pageable pageable = getPageable(studentPage);

    long studentsCount = getStudentsCount(predicate);
    return new PageImpl<>(typedQuery.getResultList(), pageable, studentsCount);
}




private Predicate getPredicate(StudentSearchCriteria studentSearchCriteria,
                               Root<Student> studentRoot) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Objects.nonNull(studentSearchCriteria.getFirstName())) {
        predicates.add(
                criteriaBuilder.like(studentRoot.get("firstName"),
                        "%" + studentSearchCriteria.getFirstName() + "%")
        );
    }

    if (Objects.nonNull(studentSearchCriteria.getLastName())) {
        predicates.add(
                criteriaBuilder.like(studentRoot.get("lastName"),
                        "%" + studentSearchCriteria.getLastName() + "%")
        );
    }

    if (Objects.nonNull(studentSearchCriteria.getYearOfStudy())) {
        predicates.add(
                criteriaBuilder.like(studentRoot.get("yearOfStudy"),
                        "%" + studentSearchCriteria.getYearOfStudy() + "%")
        );
    }
    return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}
```

Comment: Seems like a copy and paste error. yearsOfStudy is an integral field so a "LIKE" query does not make sense on the latest if block in `getPredicate`

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl and how should it be, because that is my code, is not a copy paste error

Comment: if what you wanted to do is to an "exact match" of `yearsOfStudy`, then you should not be using `Like` criteria anyway.

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl Any suggestion, on what should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA can't execute `like` query between `Integer` and `String`. Try to convert `Interger` to `String` in `yearOfStudy`

```
if (Objects.nonNull(studentSearchCriteria.getYearOfStudy())) {
      predicates.add(
          criteriaBuilder.like(studentRoot.get("yearOfStudy").as(String.class), "%" + studentSearchCriteria.getYearOfStudy() + "%")
      );
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not perform exact match. If your query has `yearOfStudy` as `1` it will match with every entry in the DB that has the number `1` in it, e. g. `10` `15` `21` etc. will also match since they have the number `1` in them. It is a terrible behavior to depend on.

Comment: Any suggestion, on what should I use instead?

Comment: Try `criteriaBuilder.equal(studentRoot.get("yearOfStudy"), studentSearchCriteria.getYearOfStudy())` instead, as you should be checking equality and not string matching.